# How to download all photos of a specific month in Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos

The only way I found is using Google Takeout to download *all* pictures.

However, I need only the pictures of one specific month.

With the recent interface at https://photos.google.com you can only click a day and download those photos as archive. Even several. But if you select more than 500 items, it is not working.